# How to call a controller inside a Razor Class Library

Tags: .net-core, razor, controller, blazor

I have a RCL defined with a controller.
Let's call it DataController and here is how it is defined:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<string>>> LetsBreakIt()
```

This controller is placed inside a folder call Controllers at the root level of the library.
From a Razor component, I try the following code:

```
string uri = $"Data/LetsBreakIt";

        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            ssiList = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<string>>(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
```

But I have this error:

> An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an
> absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.

Of course, I tried to set the uri starting with "/" but it gave me the same error.
I tried to add (without success):

```
[ApiController]
```

In my Blazor application, in the startup.cs this is what is currently mapped:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the NavigationManager to get the base URI and then use it:

```
    var absoluteUri = NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("Data/LetsBreakIt");
    
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = absoluteUri;
        ssiList = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<string>>("");
    }
```